# How to generate a frequency based sound (like 750Hz in 4 seconds) in Lua?

Tags: audio, lua

You know that you can generate sound put in frequency (Hertz), but how do you create a sound where it will play a set amount of time in random Hertz? Like, you want to play 750Hz in 4 seconds. Is it possible to do that in Lua?

I was thinking about `os.execute("echo \7")` but that just creates a random beeping. I want to control the sound I create in a set amount of time and a set amount of frequency.

Answer (score 0):

os.execute runs shell commands. Lua on its own cannot create sounds or set frequencies.

So you're actually asking how to beep from your shell for a given amount of time.

This could be achieved by `powershell "[console]::beep(<frequency>, <duration_ms>)"`

so `os.execute('powershell "[console]::beep(4000, 1000)"'`

should play a 4kHz sound for 1s.

Alternatively find a Lua library that play configurable tones.

Comment: But which languages can generate frequencies of sounds on it's own?

Comment: actually none. you always need something in between if you want to talk to hardware. but for interpreted languages like Lua you even need a step more than with other languages. Lua is an interpreted language that is usually embedded into another application that is written in C or C++. and that C or C++ application still needs a driver or some API to talk to hardware.

Comment: And what drivers and API do these languages use?

Comment: The one you would like to use, without more information it's hard to recommend one. Can you share more details about your project? Can you use more high level frameworks instead of plain Lua?

Comment: @gylotip for example the [waveOut functions in winmm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/waveform-functions) on Windows. On Linux: varies...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in LuaJIT

```
local ffi = require'ffi'
ffi.cdef "int Beep(int Frequency_Hz, int Duration_Milliseconds)"
ffi.C.Beep(750, 4000)
```